# How validate a select field on the same button click that opens a modal?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to validate a select which is required to select an option to continue with the process. If any option is not selected then it should give an alert box, else it should open the modal. In my case the modal gets opened either way.

```
<select  class="form-control" id="account_name"  name="account_name">
<option  value="">Select Customer..</option>
     <?php
    while ($rows = pg_fetch_assoc($result)) { ?>
          <option value="<?= $rows['address1'] . ' ' . 
              $rows['address2'] . ' ' . $rows['address3'] .' '.$name. '-' . 
              $rows['account_code']; ?>"><?= $rows['account_name']; ?>
          </option>
     <?php } ?>
 </select>

  <div class="wrapper1" id='business1'>
       <input type="submit" id="myBtn"  value="New Order" style="height:55px; width:170px; margin-left: -50px;" class="btn btn-success" />
  </div>

<!-- JQUERY -->

 $(document).ready(function () {
      $("#myBtn").click(function () {
         if ($("#account_name").val() === NULL){
            alert('Please select an option');           
         }
         else
         {
            $('#myModal').modal('show');
         }
      });
  });
```

With this code, the modal doesn't get displayed on any selection, and neither the alert box is displayed.

I also tried doing this

```
 <select  class="form-control" id="account_name" name="account_name" 
 required>
```

Although the validation gets applied here, still the modal is opened on submit if no option is selected.

Comment: Have you tried if check for empty instead? if($("#account_name").val() == "")

Comment: javascript is case-sensitive, so `NULL` isn't `null`.  Javascript also tries to be helpful and converts variables (like your `NULL`) to a string if they don't exist, so your code is saying `if ($(...).val() === 'NULL')` which is never true, hence the modal appearing.  Javascript also converts any falsey value to false... so `null`, `''`, `0`, and `undefined` are all false, and I assume you aren't using `0` or `''` as one of your options so you can simply `if (!$(...).val())`, instead

Comment: Please a) properly indent your code b) post final HTML for client-side questions (not PHP) (also don't use a value like that; just use the id; all that data is available on the server anyway)

Comment: @leroystav thanks. i just know this info

Comment: mpj.. I tried that. I am still getting the same output

Comment: Thank you Leroy. That worked :)

Comment: @LeroyStav - Please convert your comment to an answer so it can be upvoted/selected as correct answer.

Comment: Without the rest of the code it was just an educated guess and not an answer, hence the comment :-) Now that we know it is correct I went ahead and did so, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

javascript is case-sensitive, so NULL isn't null. Javascript also tries to be helpful and converts variables (like your NULL) to a string if they don't exist, so your code is saying if ($(...).val() === 'NULL') which is never true, hence the modal appearing. Javascript also converts any falsey value to false... so null, '', 0, and undefined are all false, and I assume you aren't using 0 or '' as one of your options so you can simply if (!$(...).val()), instead